# fried garam masala tastes watery

Tags: oil, water, powder

Recently I've been frying garam masala because I want some tasty oil(which should not be watery).  At first it was kind of working however it now seems the oil is watery and not thick or oily if you know what I mean.

The problem is I'm not adding any water.  However I have been adding more powder than usual.  Does the powder contain water and might too much powder be the cause of a watery marinade if I may call it that. If not too much marinade what else could be causing the watery marinade, how much should I add?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what oil tasting watery means. If there were water there, then you could let it sit and see it separate. Can you find a different way to describe the taste? Does it taste less like garam masala? Does it taste more like raw garam masala? Or is the *texture* different? Have you changed anything at all besides adding more masala to the same amount of oil?

Comment: Please describe what you are doing, step by step, because at present it is quite confusing. Are you saying that the act of adding Garamond masala to the oil has reduced the oil’s [viscosity](https://www.princeton.edu/~gasdyn/Research/T-C_Research_Folder/Viscosity_def.html)?

Comment: @Spagirl it seems that way yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make oil have powder garam masala taste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/91421/how-to-make-oil-have-powder-garam-masala-taste)

Answer (score 0):

If moisture is coming from the garam masala then gently cooking it a little longer would evaporate any moisture. Perhaps you are using too many spices for the amount of oil.